# How to Generate Control flow graph from a Petri net model?

Tags: formal-methods, software-verification, software-testing, petri-nets

My research is mainly focused on generating test sequences automatically using Colored Petri net.CFG provides techniques for generating test sequences. But some papers says that, test sequence generation methods based on a control flow graph sometimes suffers from a feasibility problem (i.e. some paths in a CFG may not be feasible).So I need a technique to draw a Control flow graph from the Colored Petri net model, in a way that, when I will select paths from the control-flow graph it will contain only the feasible paths.Then I will generate test sequences from the CFG. Can anyone help me finding any technique please or give me any suggession??

Comment: Have you asked your advisor?

Comment: My research is mainly focused on generating test sequences automatically using Colored Petri net.CFG provides techniques for generating test sequences. But some papers says that, test sequence generation methods based on a control flow graph sometimes suffers from a feasibility problem (i.e. some paths in a CFG may not be feasible). As rechability graphs takes only feasible paths so I figured out if I can generate a CFG from the RG then every path will be feasible.So I need a technique to draw a Control flow graph from the Rechability graph.Then I will generate test sequences from the CFG.

Comment: Sounds like an instance of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/160917).  Sounds like what you really need is a way to generate a control-flow graph for a Petri net, in a way that doesn't "suffer from a feasibility problem" (whatever that means -- I think you need to make that more precise).  Whether it's via a reachability graph or some other way presumably doesn't matter if it achieves that goal.  Is that right?  If so, can you edit your question to focus on the goal without making unwarranted assumptions about what kind of method will be needed to achieve that goal?

Comment: Actually yes, I need a technique to generate a control-flow graph for a Colored Petri net, in a way that, when I will select paths from the control-flow graph it will not contain any infeasible path. Can you please suggest me any technique?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are interested in generating test sequences automatically using colored Petri nets, note that it's not clear that you need reduction to control flow graphs (and dealing with all the related issues). Some techniques were presented, that use various different methods to generate test sequences from Petri nets. Some examples include:

[H. Watanabe and T. Kudoh, "Test suite generation methods for concurrent systems based on coloured Petri nets," Software Engineering Conference, 1995. Proceedings., 1995 Asia Pacific, Brisbane, Qld., 1995, pp. 242-251.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=496973)

[J. Desel, A. Oberweis, T. Zimmer and G. Zimmermann, "Validation of information system models: Petri nets and test case generation," Systems, Man, and Cybernetics, 1997. Computational Cybernetics and Simulation., Orlando, FL, 1997, pp. 3401-3406 vol.4.](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=633178)

[Xu, Dianxiang. "A tool for automated test code generation from high-level Petri nets." Applications and Theory of Petri Nets. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011. 308-317.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-21834-7_17)

On the other hand, since Petri nets and control flow graphs are not semantically equivalent in general (and capture different type of information), the translation between the two is usually done in some specific domain (and restrictions). (Although usually, control flow graphs can be transformed into equivalent Petri nets.). Some examples and discussions are given in:

[De Jong, Gjalt G. "Data flow graphs: system specification with the most unrestricted semantics." Proceedings of the conference on European design automation. IEEE Computer Society Press, 1991.](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=951600)

[The Design Of A General Method For Constructing Coupled Scientific Simulations, Matthew J. Sottile](http://www.cs.uoregon.edu/research/paracomp/papers/mattms/matt_msthesis.pdf)

Note that your question seems a bit too general. (Moreover, it also seems as an instance of XY, as noted by D.W.) Without more details, it seems hard to give a concrete and concise answer. Hopefully, given pointers can get you closer to your desired goal.